# Local linearization / calculus

Tags: calculus

The question is : 
Local linearization gives values too small for the function x2 and too large for the function . Draw pictures to explain why.

See vvv that is the question only. No additional things are given.

### [image]

What I want is:

I need a explanation and How to draw a linearization ?

---

What I know about linearization is:

I know how to find the local linearzation, but there aren't any given x values and its not stated which is the function and which is the tangent function.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @copper.hat I fixed it :)

Comment: Where did you find this exercise ?

Comment: You need more information.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo In my textbook.

Comment: @copper.hat nope that is the question only :(, check i posted a picture of it.

Comment: Can you give the title of your textbook ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Hughes-Hallett, Calculus: 6e

Comment: "there aren't any given x values": for this exercise, any value of $x$ will do. "its not stated which is the function": there are clearly two given functions: $x^2$ and $\sqrt x$. The tangent function is the one you are asked to draw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^2$.  The "local linearization" of $f$ at $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ is the function
$h(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0)$.  The graph of $h$ is a line which is tangent to the graph of $f$ at the point $(x_0,f(x_0))$.

Just graph $f$ then pick some $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ and graph $h$.  The picture will show that the graph of $h$ lies below the graph of $f$.  In other words, if $x_0 \in \mathbb R$, then
$f(x) \geq f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0)$ for all $x$.